# Error enabling OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and trying to work with some of the example apps from Josh Long and Dave Syer.

I have the following code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Resource
@RestController
public class SsoResourceApplication {
@RequestMapping("/hi")
public Map<String, Object> hi(Principal principal) {
    System.out.println("received request from " + principal.getName());
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    result.put("content", "Hello, world!");
    return result;
}
```

With the dependencies defined so

```
compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.8.RELEASE.jar')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security:1.0.4.RELEASE')
```

When I start up I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you omitted the property `spring.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri` in your application.properties (or application.yml). This property must point to a URI within your authorization server. Here is a [Spring boot 1.2 to 1.3 migration document](https://spring.io/blog/2015/11/30/migrating-oauth2-apps-from-spring-boot-1-2-to-1-3#resource-server).

I assume you have an authorization server in your environment, so that the user Info URI can point to. 
You also migh want to have a look at the [Spring boot OAuth2 tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/).

Finally, you would see that most recent examples use `@EnableResourceServer` rather than `@EnableOAuth2Resource`. They are equivalent, but the former does not require a dependency on spring cloud and the configuration property is slightly different (`security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri`). It's all explained in the Spring boot 1.2 to 1.3 migration document.